# Configure LDAPS Wildfly 25 Elytron

Tags: java, ldap, wildfly, elytron

I am trying to configure LDAPS on Elytron on Wildfly 25 and I do not know what I'm missing.

I always get this error because the server rejects non SSL connections:

```
2021-10-12 09:54:53,597 DEBUG [org.wildfly.security] (default task-1) Could not create [class javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext]. Failed to connect to LDAP server.: javax.naming.CommunicationException: LDAP.example:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out]
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:253)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:137)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1616)
```

I guess I'm missing something in the dir-context in standalone.xml, any ideas?

```
            <dir-contexts>
            <dir-context name="ldap-connection" url="LDAPS://LDAP.example:636" authentication-level="simple" principal="CN=......." ssl-context="LocalhostSslContext">
                <credential-reference clear-text="pass"/>
            </dir-context>
        </dir-contexts>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of usage:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron:1.0" final-providers="combined-providers" disallowed-providers="OracleUcrypto">
  ...
  <security-realms>
    ...
    <ldap-realm name="ldap-realm" dir-context="ldap-connection" direct-verification="true">
      <identity-mapping rdn-identifier="uid" search-base-dn="ou=users,dc=group-to-principal,dc=wildfly,dc=org">
        <attribute-mapping>
          <attribute from="uid" to="Roles" filter="(uniqueMember={1})" filter-base-dn="ou=groups,dc=group-to-principal,dc=wildfly,dc=org"/>
        </attribute-mapping>
      </identity-mapping>
    </ldap-realm>
  </security-realms>
  ...
  <dir-contexts>
    <dir-context name="ldap-connection" url="ldap://localhost:10389" principal="uid=admin,ou=system">
      <credential-reference clear-text="secret"/>
    </dir-context>
  </dir-contexts>
</subsystem>
```

For reference: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/LDAP%20Based%20Authentication%20Migration.html

-- Updated --

Reference ldap.xml for setting up LDAP for testing that could be usefull.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron:14.0" initial-providers="elytron">
   <authentication-client>
      <authentication-configuration name="ldapAuthConfig" authentication-name="uid=server,dc=users,dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org">
         <credential-reference clear-text="serverPassword"/>
      </authentication-configuration>
      <authentication-context name="ldapAuthContext">
         <match-rule match-host="localhost" match-protocol="ldaps" authentication-configuration="ldapAuthConfig" ssl-context="LdapSslContext"/>
         <match-rule match-host="localhost" match-protocol="ldap" authentication-configuration="ldapAuthConfig"/>
      </authentication-context>
   </authentication-client>
   <providers>
      <provider-loader name="elytron" class-names="org.wildfly.security.WildFlyElytronProvider" />
   </providers>
   <security-realms>
      <ldap-realm name="LdapRealm" dir-context="DirContextSsl">
         <identity-mapping filter-name="(|(objectclass=referral)(uid={0}))" iterator-filter="(|(objectclass=referral)(uid=*))" new-identity-parent-dn="dc=users,dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org" rdn-identifier="uid" search-base-dn="dc=users,dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org" use-recursive-search="true">
            <attribute-mapping>
               <attribute to="userDn"/>
               <attribute from="uid" to="userName"/>
               <attribute from="cn" to="firstName"/>
               <attribute from="sn"/>
               <attribute from="telephoneNumber" to="phones"/>
               <attribute filter="(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member={1}))" filter-base-dn="dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org" to="rolesDn"/>
               <attribute filter="(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member={1}))" filter-base-dn="dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org" to="rolesRecRdnCn" role-recursion="2" extract-rdn="CN"/>
               <attribute filter="(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member={1}))" filter-base-dn="dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org" to="rolesCn" extract-rdn="CN"/>
               <attribute filter="(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member={1}))" filter-base-dn="dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org" from="description" to="rolesDescription" role-recursion="2"/>
               <attribute filter="(&amp;(objectClass=organizationalRole)(description={0}))" filter-base-dn="dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org" from="street" to="rolesByName" role-recursion="2" role-recursion-name="postalCode"/>
               <attribute reference="memberOf" from="description" to="memberOfDescription" role-recursion="5"/>
               <attribute reference="memberOf" to="memberOfDn" role-recursion="3"/>
            </attribute-mapping>
            <new-identity-attributes>
               <attribute name="objectClass" value="top inetOrgPerson person organizationalPerson otpToken"/>
               <attribute name="sn" value="BlankSurname"/>
               <attribute name="cn" value="BlankCommonName"/>
            </new-identity-attributes>
            <user-password-mapper from="userPassword" writable="true"/>
            <otp-credential-mapper algorithm-from="otpAlgorithm" hash-from="otpHash" seed-from="otpSeed" sequence-from="otpSequence"/>
            <x509-credential-mapper digest-from="x509digest" certificate-from="usercertificate" subject-dn-from="x509subject" serial-number-from="x509serialNumber" />
         </identity-mapping>
      </ldap-realm>
      <ldap-realm name="LdapRealmDirectVerification" dir-context="DirContextSsl" direct-verification="true" allow-blank-password="true">
         <identity-mapping filter-name="(|(objectclass=referral)(uid={0}))" iterator-filter="(uid=*)" new-identity-parent-dn="dc=users,dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org" rdn-identifier="uid" search-base-dn="dc=users,dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org" use-recursive-search="true">
         </identity-mapping>
      </ldap-realm>
      <ldap-realm name="LdapRealmCharset" dir-context="DirContextSsl" hash-charset="GB2312">
         <identity-mapping filter-name="(|(objectclass=referral)(uid={0}))" iterator-filter="(|(objectclass=referral)(uid=*))" new-identity-parent-dn="dc=users,dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org" rdn-identifier="uid" search-base-dn="dc=users,dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org" use-recursive-search="true" >
            <attribute-mapping>
               <attribute to="userDn"/>
               <attribute from="uid" to="userName"/>
               <attribute from="cn" to="firstName"/>
               <attribute from="sn"/>
            </attribute-mapping>
            <user-password-mapper from="userPassword" writable="true"/>
         </identity-mapping>
      </ldap-realm>

      <ldap-realm name="LdapRealmEncodingCharset" dir-context="DirContextSsl" hash-charset="GB2312" hash-encoding="hex">
         <identity-mapping filter-name="(|(objectclass=referral)(uid={0}))" iterator-filter="(|(objectclass=referral)(uid=*))" new-identity-parent-dn="dc=users,dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org" rdn-identifier="uid" search-base-dn="dc=users,dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org" use-recursive-search="true" >
            <attribute-mapping>
               <attribute to="userDn"/>
               <attribute from="uid" to="userName"/>
               <attribute from="cn" to="firstName"/>
               <attribute from="sn"/>
            </attribute-mapping>
            <user-password-mapper from="userPassword" writable="true"/>
         </identity-mapping>
      </ldap-realm>
   </security-realms>
   <tls>
      <key-stores>
         <key-store name="ElytronCaTruststore" >
            <credential-reference clear-text="Elytron"/>
            <implementation type="JKS" />
            <file path="ca.truststore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
         </key-store>
         <ldap-key-store dir-context="DirContextSsl" name="LdapKeyStoreMinimal">
            <search path="ou=keystore,dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org"/>
         </ldap-key-store>
         <ldap-key-store dir-context="DirContextSsl" name="LdapKeyStoreMaximal">
            <new-item-template new-item-path="ou=keystore,dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org" new-item-rdn="cn">
               <attribute name="objectClass" value="top inetOrgPerson"/>
               <attribute name="sn" value="NewKeyStoreItem"/>
            </new-item-template>
            <search path="dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org" recursive="true" time-limit="1000" filter-alias="(&amp;(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(sn={0}))"
                    filter-certificate="(&amp;(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(usercertificate={0}))" filter-iterate="(sn=serenity*)"/>
            <attribute-mapping alias-attribute="sn" certificate-attribute="usercertificate" certificate-chain-attribute="userSMIMECertificate" certificate-chain-encoding="PKCS7" certificate-type="X.509"/>
         </ldap-key-store>
      </key-stores>
      <key-managers>
         <key-manager name="LdapKeyManager" key-store="LdapKeyStoreMaximal">
            <credential-reference clear-text="Elytron"/>
         </key-manager>
      </key-managers>
      <trust-managers>
         <trust-manager key-store="ElytronCaTruststore" name="ElytronTrustManager"/>
      </trust-managers>
      <client-ssl-contexts>
         <client-ssl-context name="LdapSslContext" protocols="SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1" trust-manager="ElytronTrustManager"/>
      </client-ssl-contexts>
   </tls>
   <dir-contexts>
      <dir-context authentication-level="none" authentication-context="ldapAuthContext" name="DirContextInsecure" url="ldap://localhost:11391/"/>
      <dir-context name="DirContextSsl" authentication-context="ldapAuthContext" referral-mode="throw" url="ldaps://localhost:11391/" connection-timeout="6000" read-timeout="10000">
         <properties>
            <property name="java.naming.dns.url" value="dns://dnsserver/wiz.com"/>
         </properties>
      </dir-context>
      <dir-context name="DirContextSslCredential" url="ldaps://localhost:11391/" principal="uid=server,dc=users,dc=elytron,dc=wildfly,dc=org" ssl-context="LdapSslContext">
         <credential-reference clear-text="serverPassword"/>
      </dir-context>
   </dir-contexts>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: Thank you Susan, but caps are not the problem. I checked the examples on the jboss/wildfly documentation, but there is no reference for LDAP over SSL, which is probably what is missing.

Comment: See if this helps you get started @Lluc https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/main/elytron/src/test/resources/org/wildfly/extension/elytron/ldap.xml  I know it is a test configuration but it can give you pointers :)

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, I got the ldap connection fixed thanks to this example. I'll post an answer with the relevant bits. Thank you Susan!

Answer (score 3):

The issue was the way I was using the truststore, after I reconfigured it like so, it worked.
Full example: https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/main/elytron/src/test/resources/org/wildfly/extension/elytron/ldap.xml

Extract:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron:14.0" final-providers="combined-providers" disallowed-providers="OracleUcrypto">
    ...
    <tls>
        <key-stores>
            ...
            <key-store name="TrustStore">
                <credential-reference clear-text="secret" />
                <implementation type="JKS" />
                <file path="truststore.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" />
            </key-store>
        </key-stores>
        ...
        <trust-managers>
            <trust-manager name="TrustManager" key-store="TrustStore" />
        </trust-managers>
        ...
        <client-ssl-contexts>
            <client-ssl-context name="LdapSslContext" protocols="SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1" trust-manager="TrustManager" />
        </client-ssl-contexts>
    </tls>
    <dir-contexts>
        <dir-context name="ldap-connection" url="ldaps://ldap.example:636" principal="CN=user...." ssl-context="LdapSslContext">
            <credential-reference clear-text="secret" />
        </dir-context>
    </dir-contexts>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: In my environment the <client-ssl-contexts> was exact the right point, because the LDAP server certificates wasn't part of the Java cacerts. When Wildfly/JBoss connects to the LDAP(s) server, the "ssl-context" from own truststore is now used as a client.